# What is the best way to perform a RegEx test over multiple model fields?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, functional-programming

If I have the following model:

```
data = [
  {comment: 'Blue eyes', label: 'Red', User: 'John Doe', total: 345},
  {comment: 'Bye', label: 'Blue', User: 'Jane Doe', total: 497},
  {comment: 'Whatever', label: 'Green', User: 'Blues Saraceno', total: 987}
]
```

And I need to filter the results from an existing **filterString**. E.g 'blue'
What is the best way to apply:

```
const filterRegex = new RegExp(filterString, 'i')
```

To all of the model fields? No mmater if the sting is in the comment, user, label or total ?

I really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: What end result do you want?

Comment: don't forget that regexp has its own special control sequences. so you will not be able to search for "(45)" without escaping it like "\\(45\\)"

Comment: Fir this particular example I would expect to have the 3 records as all of them had **blue** into their fields values

Comment: If the filter is only a word and never a regex I would use "includes(filterWord)" over regexing.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm will filter both the array and the objects inside the array. Will look for a REGEXP match inside all of the values in your objects an will return an array of the objects that at least had on matching value

Hope this helps :)

```js
var data = [
  {comment: 'Blue eyes', label: 'Red', User: 'John Doe', total: 345},
  {comment: 'Bye', label: 'Red', User: 'Jane Doe', total: 497},
  {comment: 'Whatever', label: 'Green', User: 'Blues Saraceno', total: 987}
]


const filterRegex = new RegExp('blue', 'i')

var newA = data.filter(el=>{
  let filterd = Object.values(el).filter(el=> el.toString().match(filterRegex) != null)
  if(filterd.length != 0)
  return el
})

console.log(newA)
```

Comment: @LeonardoUribe did my answer helped? I would be happy to edit if you need something different

Answer (score 0):

The logic will need to check every object but since only one value needs to match the filter string then it only needs to match one of the values (i.e. there is no need to check every value if a match already occurred). This can be accomplished with using the native Array method of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for removing non-matching objects and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for matching only once per set of object values.

The function would look like something like this:

```
function filter(filterStr, data) {
  const filterRegex = new RegExp(filterStr, 'i');

  // Iterate over data array and only return matching objects
  return data.filter((o) =>
    // Only check values until one matches
    Object.values(o).some((v) =>
      filterRegex.test(v)
    )
  );
}
```

And a working example:

```js
const data = [{
    comment: 'Blue eyes',
    label: 'Red',
    User: 'John Doe',
    total: 345
  },
  {
    comment: 'Bye',
    label: 'Blue',
    User: 'Jane Doe',
    total: 497
  },
  {
    comment: 'Whatever',
    label: 'Green',
    User: 'Blues Saraceno',
    total: 987
  }
];

function filter(filterStr, data) {
  const filterRegex = new RegExp(filterStr, 'i');

  // Iterate over data array and only return matching objects
  return data.filter((o) =>
    // Only check values until one matches
    Object.values(o).some((v) =>
      filterRegex.test(v)
    )
  );
}

console.log(filter('Blue', data));
```